# Convert HttpServletRequest to JSON as "UTF-8"

Tags: java, json, spring, utf-8

I have method, which converts `HttpServletRequest` to JSON format:

```
public JsonObject requestToJson(HttpServletRequest request){

        StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
        String line = null;
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                jb.append(line);
        } catch (Exception e) { /*report an error*/ }

        return new JsonParser().parse(jb.toString()).getAsJsonObject();
    }
```

The problem is, how to convert request as "UTF-8" encoding?

**UPDATED:** I checked, by default reader takes request as "ISO-8859-1". How to set parameter to reader, that it took it as "UTF-8".

Answer (score 1):

I found solution myself. I just added to top:

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to `use request.setCharacterEncoding( "UTF-8")`, but this method doesn't really work on GET parameters.

Another way is manually convert to UTF-8:

```
BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    jb.append(new String(line.getBytes(), "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: It's not GET parameters. Also, your example code is dangerous. `line.getBytes()` will use the platform default encoding which is basically a random value depending on which machine you run it on.

Comment: I checked, by default reader takes request as "ISO-8859-1". How to set parameter to reader, that it took it as "UTF-8"